# Why do docker images need to be small?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to determine the material benefits of ensuring that your docker images are small.  It seems that folks jump through some serious hoops to achieve this but the benefits aren't clear to me.

Let's take [a nodejs base image](https://imagelayers.iron.io/?images=node:5.4.1) as an example.  Yeah it's huge and would take a good amount time / bandwidth to pull from the registry, but since it's used as a base image doesn't that need to happen just once?  After that the host has it cached and going forward doesn't need to pull it (unless we update the version of node that's used, which wouldn't happen very often).

Is the push / pull time from the registry the only downside?  If so it doesn't seem worth it to me to go through so much trouble to keep my images small.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the goal of keeping the image small is just a way of achieving a more important goal, which is making image deployment, startup time, and memory usage as minimal as possible.  The image is just a file on disk.  The container is the business end.